# Definition for function _IO_file_init and _IO_file_fopen

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am studying the implementation of C library function `fopen()` in Linux so I checked the glibc source code. In the source code I found how the fopen is implemented. But in the implementation of fopen two functions are called "`_IO_file_init`" and "`_IO_file_fopen`". But definition of these functions is not in the glibc source code.

Could any one please tell me where I can found the definition of functions "`_IO_file_init`" and "`_IO_file_fopen`".

Comment: Try using a recursive grep on the entire source tree.

Comment: I am doing an ack through my glib folder now, I will send you the path if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is in file Fileops.c. Please note _IO_new_file_fopen is an alias of _IO_file_fopen.

```
_IO_FILE *
_IO_new_file_fopen (fp, filename, mode, is32not64)
     _IO_FILE *fp;
     const char *filename;
     const char *mode;
     int is32not64;
{
  int oflags = 0, omode;
  int read_write;
  int oprot = 0666;
  int i;
  _IO_FILE *result;
#ifdef _LIBC
  const char *cs;
  const char *last_recognized;
#endif

  if (_IO_file_is_open (fp))
    return 0;
  switch (*mode)
    {
    case 'r':
      omode = O_RDONLY;
...
}
```

BTW, I am looking at glic-2.19.